# Navbar is not fully transparent

Tags: css, react-native-navigation

Hello i want to make my navbar transparen on some screens but I can't get full transparency..

When I set

```
drawUnderNavBar: true,
navBarTranslucent: true,
navBarTransparent: true,
navBarBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
navBarButtonColor: '#ffffff'
```

I get the transparent navbar with borders... Why is that I want full transparency[image]

Comment: That's not a border but a box shadow

Comment: inspect element and see box-shadow, outlines, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

you're using box-shadow property in parent so remove it then check

Comment: Yes its box shadow

Comment: This is not an solution for the actual question if you have a suggestion post it in the comments. Unless its an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved my problem. I was missing `topBarElevationShadowEnabled: false, // (Android - default: true, iOS - default: false). Disables TopBar elevation shadow on Lolipop and above` property in the options for style.

`drawUnderNavBar: true,
        navBarTranslucent: true,
        navBarTransparent: true,
        navBarButtonColor: '#ffffff',
        topBarElevationShadowEnabled: false`

This is working as expected